# Import variable in an ObservableObject

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I would like to import an actual variable set inside an ObservableObject :

My code is :

```
import SwiftUI

 struct HomepageView: View {

    @ObservedObject var obs = observer()
    var myMainVar: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
       // My view here... does not matter
    }
 }

 class observer : ObservableObject{

    init() { // how to import my variable myMainVar inside my init ?
       loadDataByAlamofire()
    }

    private func loadDataByAlamofire() { // how to import this variable in the private func?
       var url = "blabla.xyz?boolean="+myMainVar
    }
 }
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You mean you want to pass it in when your `observer` is created?

Comment: Exactly. I want to give some params to the init of my observer, before doing the Alamofire request.

Comment: A custom init for HomepageView might work to pass things in. You have to initialize the storage though, not the wrapped value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put `myMainVar` within the observer class so it can be used within any of the fuctions. Then, mark the variable with `@Published` so that any changes in the variable trigger a view reload. Finally, access the variable in your view via dot syntax: `obs.myMainVar`.

For example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomepageView: View {
@ObservedObject var obs = observer()

   var body: some View {
      // My view here... does not matter

      // Display value of variable in text
      Text("\(obs.myMainVar)")
   }
}

class observer : ObservableObject{

   @Published var myMainVar: Bool = true

   init() { // how to import my variable myMainVar inside my init ?
      loadDataByAlamofire()
   }

   private func loadDataByAlamofire() { // how to import this variable in the private func?
      var url = "blabla.xyz?boolean="+myMainVar
   }
}
```

See: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/observable-objects-environment-objects-and-published